# Нужен компонент для импорта из файла Excel для Delphi 7

Tags: oracle, delphi, excel

Очень нужен компонент для импорта из файла Excel для Delphi 7 или в этом роде. Надо данные из файла сохранить в Базе Данных Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, такого компонента нет.

Берите файл Excel переводите его в CSV загружайте в программу в виде простого списка с разделителем ";" парсите и пишите в базу.

```
uses ..., ComObj;

procedure XlsToCsv (n1:string; n2:string); // Преобразование форматов
var
  ExcelApp,  WorkBook: variant;
begin
  ExcelApp:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts:=False;
  WorkBook:=ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(n1);
  ExcelApp.Visible:=false;
  WorkBook.SaveAs(n2, 6); // xlCSV = 6,   xlCSVMac = 22,   xlCSVMSDOS = 24,
  WorkBook.Close; //или юзер ничего не увидел
  ExcelApp.quit;
end;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Попробую...